# Web Api With Existing Database

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I need to create a web REST API from my existing database..

I have created a new application, added a database in models folder [Ado.net data entity model] (successfully added) and created a new controller with template 'Api controller with read/write actions, using Entity Framework' and started browsing the application with API routing 'localhost:1033/api/products..

This throws the exception:

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.

Can anyone help me with this..

Comment: Please provide some more information on what your are trying to return from your api method. You have something that doesn't serialize, you could be probably be facing reference loop. With that said, I would not recommend returning your EF entities, instead build View Models.

Comment: Provide the code for the api/products endpoint